# styled a HRef Float right not working CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design both a print and send button using a styled HRef, below is the way the button is expected to look like, but my `float: right;` is not working.

***Expected:***

[image]
[image]

***But this is what I am getting after much trial because float: right; is not working:***

[image]

```css
/* CSS */

#print-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #27A9F8;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #27A9F8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#send-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #27A9F8;
  border: 1px solid #27A9F8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  margin-right: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="result-remark">1st position in the class of 45 student’s</h2>
    <h3 id="teachers-remark">An execellent chemistry student, but needs to work hard on other subjects.</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="text-right">
    <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="print-btn"><i class="mdi mdi-printer print-ico"></i> Print</a>
    <a href="#" id="send-btn">Send</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `float: right;` from `#send-btn`

**Edit:**
You would also need to add class `col-md-12` to the parent.

```css
#print-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #27A9F8;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #27A9F8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#send-btn {
// float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #27A9F8;
  border: 1px solid #27A9F8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  margin-right: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="result-remark">1st position in the class of 45 student’s</h2>
    <h3 id="teachers-remark">An execellent chemistry student, but needs to work hard on other subjects.</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
    <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="print-btn"><i class="mdi mdi-printer print-ico"></i> Print</a>
    <a href="#" id="send-btn">Send</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried, still the same

Comment: @Ojay Have you included `Bootstrap` css? Doesn't look like in your code sample.

Comment: @Ojay Edited the answer, please see.

Answer (score 2):

Remove float and use bootstrap class.

```
#send-btn { /* float: right; remove it */ }
```

Change this:

```
<div class="text-right">
```

To this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-right">
```

Edit - this is without any of your css. check it:

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="result-remark">1st position in the class of 45 student’s</h2>
            <h3 id="teachers-remark">An execellent chemistry student, but needs to work hard on other subjects.</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="print-btn" class="btn btn-light"><i class="mdi mdi-printer print-ico"></i> Print</a>
            <a href="#" id="send-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Send</a>
          </div>
        </div>                                                  
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Still same, am even surprised myself

Comment: Remove float from stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

Remove the float on the button and use text-align on the container?

```css
/* CSS */

#print-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #27A9F8;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #27A9F8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#send-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #27A9F8;
  border: 1px solid #27A9F8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  margin-right: 19px;

}
.text-right { text-align:right }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="result-remark">1st position in the class of 45 student’s</h2>
    <h3 id="teachers-remark">An execellent chemistry student, but needs to work hard on other subjects.</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="text-right">
    <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="print-btn"><i class="mdi mdi-printer print-ico"></i> Print</a>
    <a href="#" id="send-btn">Send</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result in my browser

[image]

Comment: Does for me in Chrome

Comment: am also using Chrome

Comment: The code above floats to the right in my browser - see the update with the screen shot

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine, wrapped it in a row i was not supposed to

Answer (score 0):

```css
    #print-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #27A9F8;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #27A9F8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#send-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #27A9F8;
  border: 1px solid #27A9F8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 11px 40px;
  margin-right: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="result-remark">1st position in the class of 45 student’s</h2>
    <h3 id="teachers-remark">An execellent chemistry student, but needs to work hard on other subjects.</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-right">
    <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="print-btn" class="btn"><i class="mdi mdi-printer print-ico"></i> Print</a>
    <a href="#" id="send-btn">Send</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="result-remark">1st position in the class of 45 student’s</h2>
    <h3 id="teachers-remark">An execellent chemistry student, but needs to work hard on other subjects.</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-right">
    <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="print-btn" class="btn"><i class="mdi mdi-printer print-ico"></i> Print</a>
    <a href="#" id="send-btn">Send</a>
  </div>
</div>
```